# SharePoint REST API - Is it possible to expand lookup column in list A to list B and get data with attachments of B at once?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, lookup

I have a list A. In this list, I have a lookup column authorId. In author list, I have some data columns and one attachment. I need to get ifformations about both - I need data and attachment too.

Is it possible in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to do a select and expand for both columns in your REST call similar to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103298/expanding-columns-in-lookup-fields).

To borrow their answer:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles,authorId/FieldToExpand&$expand=AttachmentFiles,authorId
```